# spring.cloud.inetutils.ignoredInterfaces ignored in profiles

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

I'm running a Spring Boot application and using the Netflix OSS Spring Cloud framework.  We are running a Eureka instance and have a service that is trying to register. When our service registers to Eureka it uses IP of the wrong port name. To fix this we have added:

`spring.cloud.inetutils.ignoredInterfaces=eth0`

This works great when we pass this from the command line, but when we move this into a profile configuration it doesn't work but all other configuration of the profile is picked up.

So for example this will work:

```
java -jar service.jar --spring.cloud.inetutils.ignoredInterfaces=eth0
```

and this will NOT work:

```
java -jar service.jar --spring.profiles.active=localvm
```

where `application-localvm.properites` contains:
`spring.cloud.inetutils.ignoredInterfaces=eth0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look you have to add `-D` argument **before the main class or jar archive**.

So try this:

> java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=localvm service.jar

For more details check this doc about how to [set the active Spring profiles](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-set-active-spring-profiles).

Comment: That worked!  I guess the NIC card is already bound when reading properties passed in the profile via the --spring.profiles.active flag.  Thanks for your help